# Azure Key Vault Access Policy Error - Terraform Configuration Issue

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I'm using Terraform to manage Azure resources, including an Azure Key Vault. I want to grant access to a specific user or service principal using an access policy, but I'm encountering an error.

code:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                        = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.keyvault_rg.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.keyvault_rg.location
  sku_name                    = "standard"
  tenant_id                   = var.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "access_policy" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id

  tenant_id = var.tenant_id

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = var.tenant_id
    object_id = var.user_object_id

    secret_permissions = ["get", "list"]
  }
}`
```

when I run terraform apply, I receive the following error related to the access policy:

> Error: Error creating Key Vault Access Policy "access_policy" (Key
> Vault "mykeyvault"): keyvault.BaseClient#SetAccessPolicy: Failure
> sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure:
> Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadArgument"
> Message="Tenant ID in the access policy does not match tenant ID in
> the URL.

I've checked my configuration, and the tenant ID seems to be correct. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Here I was encountering an error indicating a mismatch between the tenant ID in the access policy and the tenant ID in the URL when creating the Key Vault Access Policy. The question seeks guidance on what could be causing this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here I tried to configure the key vault access along with the policy and was able to provision it successfully.

The error message suggests a mismatch between the tenant ID specified in the access policy and the tenant ID in the URL when creating the Key Vault Access Policy.

To Overcome this issue please recheck the tenant ID and provider version

**My Terraform configuration:**

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovksb"
  location = "east us"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                        = "mykeyvksbvault"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku_name                    = "standard"
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

}

data "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  display_name = "Bolli Vinay Kumar"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "access_policy" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

  key_permissions = ["Get","List"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get", "List"]
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]